# why we need to do sever side validation for google recaptcha?

Tags: validation, spring-boot, spring-security, recaptcha

In my new project, I am going to include google recaptcha.
my question is fairly simple even if we do client side validation that user is not a robot even though it is suggested to do server side validation.
I want to know why it is necessary to do server side validation for google recaptcha? how does it add the extra layer of security? and how to do in spring boot with spring security?

Answer (score 2):

Server side validation is MUST !! reCAPTCHA is designed in a way that client side just generates the 'g-captcha-response' which along with secret key (stored at server-side) is sent to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify for validation. The response is a JSON which states sucesss true or false and it is further pushed to client side. Validating only at the client side is technically possible, but it defeats the purpose. Moreover, you may get CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policy error in console if you do only client side validation. I can share steps to do simple java based server side validation in servlet. Let me know if you need that.

Comment: Yes kindly share steps to do simple java based server side validation in servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. Few points to be noted:

1. The parameter userResponse = request.getParameter("recaptchaResponse") is the way by which i am getting the 'g-recaptcha-response' generated by the user when he clicked reCAPTCHA widget on UI. On your javascript, capture the value of field 'g-recaptcha-response' and pass it appended to request. Then in servlet, we can get it from request.getParameter.
   Sample code:

   ```
    var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value;
    //alert("g-recaptcha-response= "+recaptchaResponse);
    if (recaptchaResponse.length > 0)
    { 
      var xmlhttp1;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
         xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
      else
       {
         xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       var query1 = "?recaptchaResponse=" + recaptchaResponse;
       xmlhttp1.open("POST","captchaVerificationServlet" + query1, false);
       xmlhttp1.send(null);   
       var resp1 = xmlhttp1.responseText;
       alert("resp1= "+resp1);
       if(resp1=='matched'){
           return true;
       }
       else{
           alert("resp1 did not match");
           return false;
       }
     } 
     else{
        alert("error: recaptcha response is blank");
        return false;
     }
   ```

   2. For simplicity i am checking presence of "success:true" in returned JSON response. As you know, returned JSON contains two parameters : success and error-codes. You may use a JSONReader to read and parse JSON and obtain all parameters fully. Sample code will be like 
       JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(your_inputstream);
       JsonObject jsonObject = rdr.readObject();
   3. Needless to say, remove all alerts and sop statements in production!

public class CaptchaVerificationServlet extends HttpServlet {
      private static final String sec = YOUR_SECRET_KEY;
      public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {}

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {     
        String userResponse = request.getParameter("recaptchaResponse");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        System.out.println("userResponse= "+userResponse);
        //verify user response with Google ReCaptcha API
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr(); //get client's ip address
        System.out.println("ipAddress= "+ipAddress);
        try{
            String s = validateCaptcha(sec, userResponse, ipAddress);
            Boolean success = (s.contains("\"success\": true"));
            if(success)
              response.getWriter().write("matched");
        }
        catch(Exception ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            ioe.printStackTrace(response.getWriter()); 
        }
   }

  private String validateCaptcha(String secret, String response, String remoteip) throws IOException
  {
    URLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    String output = "";
    String proxyHost = "YOUR_PROXY_NAME";
    int proxyPort = 80; //proxy server port, generally 80 or 443 (confirm from sys-admin)
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    Proxy httpProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);

    String filename = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
    String password = "changeit";
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",filename);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustAnchors",filename); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",password);

      String charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8").name();
      String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
      try {            
          String query = String.format("secret=%s&response=%s&remoteip=%s", 
          URLEncoder.encode(secret, charset),
          URLEncoder.encode(response, charset),
          URLEncoder.encode(remoteip, charset));

          URL fullURL = new URL(url + "?" + query);
          connection = fullURL.openConnection(httpProxy);
          connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0");
          is = connection.getInputStream();
          System.out.println("connection InputStream");
                  BufferedReader reader = null;
                  String responseXXX = "";
                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                  responseXXX = reader.readLine();
                  while (responseXXX!=null) {
                      output+= responseXXX;
                      responseXXX = reader.readLine();
                  }   
          System.out.println("Output: " + output);
      }
      finally {
          if (is != null) {
              try {
                  is.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  //cannot do anything here
              }
          }
      }
      return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you really appreciate it!